# Assigning the solution of an equation to a new variable

Tags: python, sage

I would like to solve a quadratic for a variable, and then assign the positive value to "C", but when I try, I get that C is 'NoneType'. Ideally I should end up with

```
C=4*sqrt(30) + 25
```

When I run the code:

```
A=5*sqrt(5)
B=2*sqrt(5)
D=var('D')
sol=solve(A^2+B^2+D^2==A*B*D,D)[1]
C=print(sol)
print(type(C))
```

I get:

```
D == 4*sqrt(30) + 25
<class 'NoneType'>
```

I am using https://sagecell.sagemath.org/ to run the code.

Comment: Try `C = sol` instead of `C = print(sol)`. And then do: `print(C)`. Or maybe if that isn't what you want try: `C = str(sol)`.

Comment: In either case, when I `print(C)`, I get `D == 4*sqrt(30) + 25`, instead of just the value

Comment: Show us the full code. I don't understand what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note about `print`: the command `print(sol)` has the side-effect
of printing out the solution, but it does not return anything,
which in Python amounts to returning `None`. Instead of
`C = print(sol)` you could do `C = sol` and then `print(C)`.

Here is a hopefully better way to go though.

Define constants and the variable:

```
sage: A = 5*sqrt(5)
sage: B = 2*sqrt(5)
sage: D = var('D')
```

Solve, using `solution_dict=True` to return solutions as dictionaries:

```
sage: sol = solve(A^2 + B^2 + D^2 == A*B*D, D, solution_dict=True)
sage: sol
[{D: -4*sqrt(30) + 25}, {D: 4*sqrt(30) + 25}]
```

Observe that sol is a list of solutions, and each solution is a dictionary.

Use one of the solutions:

```
sage: C = sol[0][D]
sage: C
-4*sqrt(30) + 25
```

or the other:

```
sage: C = sol[1][D]
sage: C
4*sqrt(30) + 25
```